# Is it possible to avoid typecast on custom @Query?

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Imagine that we have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String name;
    private Long age;
    private Boolean isMad;
...
}
```

And a repository with a trivial (and unnecessary) example for a custom query:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Info, String> {

    @Query("select p.isMad, count(*) from Person p group by p.isMad")
    List<Object> aggregateByMadness();
}
```

Now to parse this List we need to do something like this:

```
for (Object element : list) {
    Object[] result = (Object[]) element;
    Boolean isMad = (Boolean) result[0];
    Long count = (Long) result[1];
}
```

which is a pain, can we cast the result of the query directly to List of a POJO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use the [JPQL construction expression](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor):

```
package com.foo;

public class Madness {

    public Madness(boolean isMad, Number count) { /* ...*/ }
}
```

And in your repository:

```
@Query("select new com.foo.Madness(p.isMad, count(*)) from Person p group by p.isMad")
List<Madness> aggregateByMadness();
```